# Hard drive speed is slow only when booting from it

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, performance

Since I felt that my Windows 10 system wasn’t performing at its max, I decided to check the speed of the 3 drives in my machine with HD Tune. What I found out was that the system drive’s speed is around 2-5 mb/s. which of course is unacceptable.

So I decided to clone that system on to another drive, and booted from that instead.

- Result with the new drive: Same - very slow!
- Result with the old drive: Now the readings look good, 140-150 mb/s.
  Booting from the old drive afterwards made it again show as very slow, whereas the new drive would show normal reading speed (>100 mb/s).

I’m not changing any cables and not changing the SATA port they’re connected to, just changing the drive/partition being booted from in a menu created using EasyBCD.

What on earth can be causing this, and what can be done to resolve it?

Thanks!

PS: Given the nature of the problem, I’m assuming there’s no need to post a bunch of details about hard drive models etc. Correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: HDDs are notoriously bad for non-sequential access (we're talking 100x slowdown, easily, if just two processes are competing). This includes if other processes are accessing the drive while you run your benchmark (which appears to be a sequential benchmark). On Win10 you can sort the Task Manager by descending disk access to see which process is doing this. The correct solution here is to switch to a SSD. See also, https://superuser.com/questions/1276003/why-is-my-hdd-so-slow-on-the-4k-speed-tests

Comment: You´re right, I tried the program used in the other thread and see at least that it gets higher speeds on different test than what I got with HDtune.
Good I found out.. had already backed up my system, thinking it was the HD till I found out that the new system drive was slow too. 
In fact it´s not really a problem, but I thought it´s the reason why my audio starts stuttering some days after a fresh boot when there´s network activity. Already bought a new netcard and have it happening both with USB audio and with the onboard audiochip. I guess I gotta ask about that in another thread though.

Comment: Yea, if your actual problem is audio stuttering, it's probably better to ask about that separately. Don't fall into the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) trap :) Unfortunately I don't have any suggestions for audio stuttering but someone else probably will.

Comment: True JakeGould, but I saw it as information I´d spare people to chew themselfes through: If the problem really would´ve been that two completely different hdd´s would both have a hardware failure causing them to read/write at very slow speeds, it´d be an incredibly rare situation, in which knowing the brands/models wouldn´t have helped anyway - don´t you think?

Comment: Try defragging your hard drive ([Piriform Defraggler](https://www.ccleaner.com/defraggler) does the best job)

Comment: Thanks itechiegamer, I actually did that today with windows 10´s builtin tool but I´ll try with the one you mention as well!